# Do we want to do the Winter Bash this year?

Tags: discussion

Last year, the Stack Exchange ran a "[Winter Bash](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/)" across the Network as a bit of fun to end the year.  You all might remember it as "the thing with the hats," where doing certain tasks (e.g. editing a certain number of posts, having a number of upvoted questions or answers, etc) would earn you a hat (or other accessory) which you could display on your Gravatar.  This was entirely optional and every user had the option of disabling it if they chose not to participate.

Stack Exchange is doing it again this year (as they likely will for future years), and we as a site have until the beginning of December to choose whether we want to opt-in or not, and it will run from mid-December until early January.  As such, I would like to give the community a chance to weigh in, whether we as a site want to participate or not.  If this post doesn't see a lot of activity before the deadline, we'll likely just default to opt-in as we did last year.

So if you want your voices heard, please cast your votes or discuss.

---

**Update:** Given that there's apparently zero disagreement to the idea, I have submitted the opt-in form.  God willing, we'll be hatting up in a few weeks.

Comment: Up for it. Opt-in.

Comment: Yes! This would definitely raise community participation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last year I originally thought that this (WinterBash) was something to do with the non-Muslim's holidays (Christmas), but it was clarified to be that it wasn't.  If this question were asked to me, I would have said no to winterbash on this site, but seeing that it may help raise participation (as is pointed out in the comment under the question) I will say yes let us have a winterbash for this site this year, and like last year those users who want to disable and not participate in it can do so.